# tar alternative to bsdtar --include

Tags: linux, tar, bsd

I'm trying to adapt a script that uses `bsdtar`, which is not available on my Linux distribution.

```
bsdtar -x -f <file> --include="SOME/FOLDER/"
```

What is the alternative of `--include` in `tar` command?

Comment: What does bsdtar's `--include` do, or what do you actually do with it? The example given seems to be not much different from `tar -x -f <file> SOME/FOLDER/`

Comment: @muru, this will work with archive creation, not sure about extraction.

Comment: @RomeoNinov it works with both GNU and busybox tar

Comment: @muru, never tested, never used :)

Comment: I'm a bit surprised `bsdtar` is not available on your Linux distro. It's not really a hard thing to package! All the major "distro bases" have it (debian, redhat, suse, arch, slackware).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From old Solaris documentation: you can use something like:

```
tar -xf <file> $(tar -tf <file> |grep "SOME/FOLDER/")
```

For sure GNU `tar` may have options to define filter of files to be extracted but never used such options.

Comment: note that this needs to read the tar archive twice – which might not be a big deal. (or it might, if it's actually a large archive on a tape archive)

Comment: @MarcusMüller, the original source involve also rewind the tape (more long operations) :)

Comment: don't quite get that?

Comment: @MarcusMüller, `tar` = Tape ARchive. And the original article I mention in the answer was about reading from magnetic tape. and because of two `tar` commands the tape need to be rewind to the begin to start second `tar` execution from there.

Comment: Yes, exactly what I'm saying: your command needs to rewind the tape, mkrasowski's doesn't!

Answer (score 0):

Just name the folder on the command line: `tar xf tar.tar x/b`

Test

```
$rm -fr x; mkdir x x/a x/b x/b/d; touch x/nonofile x/b/f1 x/b/f2 x/b/d/f3;\
 tar cf tar.tar x;\
 rm -fr x; tar xf tar.tar x/b;\
 find x;
x
x/b
x/b/f2
x/b/d
x/b/d/f3
x/b/f1
```

'nonofile' was properly skipped but f1 f2 f3 were all extracted.